# JAVASCRIPT: IE: outerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, outerhtml

Problem i encounter with outerHTML using IE Browser

if i say:

```
txt="Update Complete!";
msg = sub.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
msg.outerHTML = txt;
```

It Works Fine:

But if i say

```
txt="1 Error:<ul><li>Some Error</li></ul>";
msg = sub.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
msg.outerHTML = txt;
```

Gives me an error of:

```
Message: Unknown runtime error
Line: 389
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://10.1.1.16/schedule_calendar/js/validate.js
```

Line:389 pertains to "msg.outerHTML = txt;"

Can anyone help me with this one.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's definitely the problem, but 'ul' isn't a valid child element of 'p'.

Comment: i'm not sure you can *set* outerHTML at all. (you can with innerHTML, tho). either way, outerHTML isn't very cross-browser compatible, so i'd consider not using it.

Comment: innerHTML doesn't exist in IE.. they have innerhtml. but it doesn't show the text. it only just stores it in innerhtml="some text". but not displaying it

Comment: `innerHTML` *does* exist in IE, although it is only writable in some situations (for example, you can't write to it for a `tbody` element, but you can for a `p`).  `outerHTML` is specific to IE and to my knowledge, will not work on any other browser.  You should avoid it.

Comment: @ Justin Johnson 

can you give me an example maybe i can work around your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons I don't know, in most cases modifying outerHTML is not allowed.
I am guessing that, this is because when you are modifying the outerHTML of an element you are actually replacing the current element.

IMO, it safer to replace a element than modifying its outerHTML.

In your case, maybe this will suffice:

**UPDATES HERE:**

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<div>
    some content...
    <div id="sub"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var sub = document.getElementById('sub');
    var txt="<p>Update Complete!</p>";
    sub.innerHTML = txt;

    alert('test 1');

    txt="1 Error:<ul><li>Some Error</li></ul>";
    sub.innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: much hunch is. <ul> and <li> are not created elements that y i got error. but do they not automatically create the said elements??

Comment: Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 5
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/preview/innerhtml.php

Comment: Sorry, but localhost will not work here, can you post the code http://pastie.org then send me the link, thanks

Comment: i know.. just try it for yourself.. use IE browser though. I just pointing out the error found by IE browser

Comment: it's working on my end, IE6,IE7 and IE8, there might be something that have caused the error, it would be nicer if we can see your code.

Comment: please see updated post, It is working on IE6,IE7,IE8, Please note though, It is not advisable to edit the DOM while the page is still loading. DOM manipulation should be done after the DOM Tree has been loaded(DOM Ready) or after the page is load (window.onload).

Comment: you can also use innerHTML for other elements except for TextNode, Comment Nodes, Most Form Elements, here are some VALID Elements for innerHTML:  p,a,span,label,b,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,5,strong,ul,li,table,tr,td,etc...

Comment: but it doesn't work with p tag.. try chaging your <div id="sub"> to <p id="sub">

i got error same as with my question

Comment: yes you're right it doesn't work in p tag if you are placing any element which is not valid in side p tag, according to w3c, p is not allowed inside p, this causes the error, p elements cannot be nested

Answer (score 0):

What is your code trying to achieve? In both cases you do:

1. create a new `p` element
2. append the `p` element to `sub` (which I assume is an element itself as well)
3. set the `outerHTML` of the `p` element to some text.

You could just as well have done:

1. create a new textNode with the desired text data
2. append that to `sub`'s childnodes:

   `sub.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Update Complete!"));`

Or, if `sub` is empty anyway, simply do:

```
sub.innerHTML = "Update Complete!";
```

Comment: Text node reads html tag as text. so it doesn't solve my problem. what i want to achieve is to add ang html text to a p element

Comment: So, just use `sub.innerHTML` then.